# Almohanad.ttf(arabic) not working fine on android 4.x

Tags: android, fonts, webview

there is app that made before android 4.0 came, that use webview to show some text(arabic) we use Almohanad.ttf font but now when we test on 4.x it is font not working as before(3.x)and it is only apply the font on some words, **tried with different font, and it working for some but other has same problem** .
please guys if any one want me to send him zip file for the part of the project that can be test easily by him, please give me your mail

Comment: please help me i did spend a lot of time  but nothing i got

Comment: Peace be upon you bro, did you find any solution for that problem ? i'm searching for a solution since more than a month, plz give me your email or any way to contact with you, thanks :)

Comment: @Ahmed SabryI am facing the same Problem , Did you find a solution for this Problem Can You help me Please ?? I have Searched and Tried many things but the Problem still

Comment: @Ahmed SabryPlease Can you help me in How to use custom arabic font for android version 4.x ?

Comment: @user Sorry bro until now I did't find a solution :(, it seems android bug. But now I preferd using android native views not webview and used typeface which works very good with all fonts :)

Comment: @Ahmed SabryThanks for your reply Oh its a bug :( but there is an arabic content phonegap & JQM  apps and they desplays the custom arabic font on my android 4.0 but i cant make it work in my app

Comment: @AhmedSabryCan you explain More Please How can I use typeface ?? I am new in jQuery mobile

Comment: Guys.....Did any one handle this problem?  I'm searching a solution for it too......